# Vertically AND horizontally center ANY content

Tags: css, dynamic, center

So, let's say I have a container, that might or might not contain any further elements and has dynamic content, i.e. text generated from database, so we don't know for sure how wide/high can it be.

How would one be able to center both horizontally AND vertically such dynamic elements?

Comment: You don't know width/height of inner div, means outer div has no width/height fixed. Then you can use padding with outer container element.

Comment: Finally, I figured it out with the `transform` property. For popups/floating anything: http://jsfiddle.net/SydXr/ For inline, horizontal centering I know of only one: `display: table; margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#center_of_viewport {
    position: fixed; /* absolute also works */
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a hack, yes. Set your container to `display: table;`, and on the text, for instance in a p, set that to `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;`. This will vertically align it.

You can combine this with `text-align` and `padding` to center horizontally.

http://jsfiddle.net/E9QF3/

Comment: Is there no way to center the container as well? I remember once I found a trick from my smartphone that uses `transform: translate(x,y)`, but unfortunately I can't find it again with Google.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of involves JavaScript to dinamically calculate the height on load, on resize or even on Ajax events. Take a look at the source of [this ALA example.](http://www.alistapart.com/d/footers/footer_variation1.html)

Comment: No way, using calc() or expressions... or even worse Javascript to calc dimensions is a very bad practice - its never bulletproof and finally its the task of CSS and the browser to render your site